# IO.read("#.../layouts/application.html.erb") return line 'applicatio...s-track' instead 'application'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have following rspec test:

```
scenario 'layout file loads assets' do
    layout_file = IO.read("#{dummy_app_path}/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb")

    expect(layout_file).to match(/stylesheet_link_tag 'application'/)
  end
```

test is red because:

```
expected "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <title>DummyApp</title>\n  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'applicatio...s-track' => true %>\n
```

Why return **applicatio...s-track**? Why no 'application'?
Can you please explain me.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your expectation as below:

```
expect(layout_file).to match(/stylesheet_link_tag\s+application'/)
```

If you look at the error message, and the actual HTML source you'll see this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'
```

Note the extraneous spaces after `stylesheet_link_tag`. That's how it's always generated from the [template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4838c1716a0340137d858fab49bf460e23be5a4b/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.tt#L9) (as long as I've known)